# no such file or directory error when pushing to heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py, heroku-cli

I'm trying to push my project to heroku but the bot keep crashing. I found this in the logs:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/venv/config.yml
```

I assumed that '/app' was the base directory of the project but I'm certain the the file exists so what am I doing wrong?

I've spent many hours searching for an answer to this but found nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `venv/`? Assuming it is where your local virtual environment is, it is very likely untracked (for good reason). Heroku's environment will be located elsewhere, and it will not contain the untracked `config.yml` file.

Comment: "I'm certain the the file exists"—please explain this certainty to us.

Comment: Thank you so much. I moved config.yml out of venv and now it works. I really appreciate your time :-)